# How can I make the controller object survive between sessions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, service, asp.net-web-api

I need my controller to store data between sessions. So if data was saved in a List in the object during a session, the data will still be there when the next session starts. Also, I need all clients to share the same controller and the data it holds, i.e. a singleton.

Apart from making all of it's members `static`, which is a bad solution, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you want to retain whole controller instance across sessions. You can just keep required list in session.

Comment: You shouldn't use singletons at all - store data in a database (perhaps in a central cache) and pull it when you need it.

Comment: @xxbbcc I think, http cache is implemented as singleton.

Comment: @T.S. You're right but cache is a framework object. And in my comment I didn't mean to use Cache but to use something like Couchbase, etc. that's accessible to more than one server.

Comment: @xxbbcc Is saving the List in the HttpRuntime.Cache and simply accessing it from there standard for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of data that should be available to multiple requests across sessions, use some kind of central repository to store it. This can be the database or a cache or even a singleton object. If the object is a run-time object (that is, you store it in a cache, not the database), don't use a singleton or HttpRuntime.Cache directly - implement some kind of an `ICache` interface and use that in the rest of your code, so you don't have a specific implementation hardcoded in your code all over the place.

For example:

```
public interface ICache
{
    void Add ( string cacheKey, object itemToAdd, TimeSpan itemLifeTime );
    object Get ( string cacheKey );
    object Remove ( string cacheKey );
}
```

This is a really simple interface, just for the example; in production code you'd want it a bit more fine-tuned with better type support, more options etc. However, it'd have to be simple enough that you can easily swap potentially incompatible implementations behind it.

Once you have this, you can create multiple cache implementations as you need them and load the one you want at run time. For example, one particular implementation could use [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as long a the data is only needed on a single server (`Cache` is local, so multiple servers on a server farm don't share the same cache).

```
public class LocalCache : ICache
{
    public void Add ( string cacheKey, object itemToAdd, TimeSpan itemLifeTime )
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add ( ... );
    }

    public object Get ( string cacheKey )
    {
        return ( HttpRuntime.Cache.Get  ( ... ) );
    }

    public object Remove ( string cacheKey )
    {
        return ( HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove ( ... ) );
    }
}
```

This would give you an implementation of a local cache. If, later on, you need a distributed cache, you can easily create a new implementation that talks to a distributed cache (Couchbase is one possibility but there are others).

Once you have your implementation, you can use an IoC library (like [LightInject](http://www.lightinject.net/) or others) to instantiate the particular implementation that you want, so you can avoid hardcoding the particular type in your code.

As you can see, `LocalCache` itself is not a singleton (it does delegate to one, because the point of a cache is that it's centrally accessible but this is hidden as an implementation detail. Other implementations would access the cache in a different manner but the interface is the same and your application would be unaware of the change.)

Comment: I see. How is using Cache different from a singleton object?

Comment: @AvivCohn It's not - `Cache` itself is a singleton. The point is that you don't want hardcoded singletons all over your code. Once you hardcode a singleton in many places, it's very hard to change it, test it, etc. You can, however, hide a particular singleton implementation behind an interface and an instance class. This way you can create other implementations of the interface and swap out the singleton with something else easily, without having to update many places in your code.

Comment: @AvivCohn This approach lets you easily start with a simple local cache (while your application is running on a single server) but you can painlessly update it to use distributed caching when your application grows and you run it on multiple servers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) or Singleton.

> all clients to share the same controller and the data it holds

**HttpRuntime.Cache** is a good choice for that scenario.

Please note that Cache will be clear when AppDomain recycle or Application crash.

### Updated:

Storing data in Memory is basically same for Cache and Singleton.

However, Cache has extra features - such as expiration and distributed caching in Web Farm and Web Garden.

```
public class Singleton
{
    static Singleton()
    {
        allSingletons = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    static readonly IDictionary<Type, object> allSingletons;

    public static IDictionary<Type, object> AllSingletons
    {
        get { return allSingletons; }
    }
}

public class Singleton<T> : Singleton
{
    static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
        set
        {
            instance = value;
            AllSingletons[typeof(T)] = value;
        }
    }
}

// Usage 
Singleton<IList<string>>.Instance = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
IList<string> collection = Singleton<IList<string>>.Instance;
```

Comment: I see. Is it 'standard' to just put a List in the HttpRuntime.Cache and simply access it from there?

Comment: Also, how is it different from Singleton? And can you link me to a resource about Singleton?

Comment: @Win Your example is not thread-safe. You should use locking or ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: @Win As far as I understand, `Cache` is not distributed - it's created once per app-domain and the instances are not synchronized.

Comment: @xxbbcc You are correct; by default, Cache is stored in server memory and only available in App Domain. However, you can use  **AppFabic** to make it Distributed cache *which is out of scope of the OP*. I'm just saying that Cache has a lot more features and offers a lot more than storing data. **thread-safe** You are correct. I only set the values at application start; I did not use it like Cache.